# Windows RunTime Component with NetworkCredential in windows 8

Tags: windows-runtime

I have created sample WindowsRunTimeComponent app in windows 8, with one property my class looks like..

```
namespace WindowsRunTimeComponentTest
{
public sealed class Class1
{
 public NetworkCredential Credentials {get; set;}
}
}
```

when I tried to build this, its giving error :

Method 'WindowsRunTimeComponentTest.class1.Credentials.get()' returns System.Net.Credentials', which is not a valid Windows Runtime type. Methods exposed to Windows Runtime must return only Windows Runtime types.

I have vs2012.
please any idea what I have to change to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is, when you create a Windows Runtime Component, your component can be used by languages that are not managed, like Javascript or C++. 
Those languages don't know how to create specific .NET types such as NetworkCredentials.

For more info see the [MSDN documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230301.aspx#DeclaringTypes) and this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13778724/system-datetime-is-not-a-valid-windows-runtime-parameter-type).